# Unable to display apis published using a tenant in another tenant's developer portal in wso2 api manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using wso2 API manager I had created and published a api with a user in test1.com tenant and i am able to see the API in test1.com tenant's developer portal but I would like to see the same for another tenant test2.com with in its own developer portal and not in first tenants developer portal.
Is it possible?
Someone please help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the API's visibility as "public" the api can be seen by other tenant users too. But the location which they are displayed is intuitively the API provider(creator)'s developer portal. This cannot be changed. For more please follow [1].

[1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/advanced-topics/control-api-visibility-and-subscription-availability-in-developer-portal/

Comment: Thank you for the Information.
Is there anyway to change this please update